# Pyplot: how to draw a normal vector?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a line:

> x + 2 * y + 1 = 0

**Python:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.5)

def f(x):
   return (-x - 1) / 2

plt.plot(x, f(x), color='blue')

plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I draw a normal to the line n(1, 2)?

Answer (score 0):

The normal line is `y=2x`, so you can draw it with

```
plt.plot(x, 2*x, color='blue')
```

In general, if you have `y=ax+b` then the normal line to it that passes through a point `(u,v)` would be `y=-(1/a)x+(1/a)u+v`.